# Python nested select on named property

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of lists such that I have an array of something like this

```
class engine:
    engines = []
    def __init__(self):
          this.modules = []

class module:
    def __init__(self,flag):
          this.someFlag = flag
```

Such that I have a list of engines, which in turn have a list of modules as the 'modules' property for each engine.

e.g.:

EngineA has ModuleA and ModuleB under EngineA.modules
EngineC has ModuleC and ModuleD under EngineC.modules

I want to search my list of engines such that I get all of the modules in a list that match a particular criteria

e.g: from all engines, select from engine.modules where someFlag = 'foo';

to select all the engines I know I do:

```
engines = [e for e in engine.engines]
```

but how do I select the modules inside 'e'?

I try something like:

```
 [m for m in e.modules for e in engine.engines]
```

but I am told e does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for ... in ...` clauses inside a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) should go in the same order as if they were normal for-loops.

Meaning, your code needs to be written like this as a list comprehension:

```
[m for e in engine.engines for m in e.modules]
```

because it would be written like this using for-loops:

```
lst = []
for e in engine.engines:
    for m in e.modules:
        lst.append(m)
```

You can read about this in [PEP 202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), where the idea of list comprehensions is introduced:

> The Proposed Solution
>
> It is proposed to allow conditional construction of list literals
>   using for and if clauses.  They would nest in the same way for
>   loops and if statements nest now.

Comment: ah, when you lay it out like that the order makes a ton more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[m for e in engine.engines for m in e.modules]
```

From [PEP 202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/):

> The form [... for x... for y...] nests, with the last index varying
>   fastest, just like nested for loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `if` part of list comprehensions. So:

```
[m for e in engine.engines for m in e.modules if m.someflag == 'foo']
```

Answer (score 2):

As much as I love list comps, I'm going to say that it might make sense to break some of that functionality into a separate function. Specifically, I think it makes sense to actually have check code that runs on each module in addition to a list comp.

```
contains_module = lambda e, f: [m for m in e if m.someFlag == f]
```

at which point, to achieve your desired query you could simply do this:

```
engines_with module = [e for e in engine.engines if contains_module(e, flag)]
```

If you want the modules instead, you could just flatten the results:

```
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
modules_with_flag = flatten([contains_module(e, flag) for e in engine.engines])
```

Comment: Not usually working in python, the list comps looked very interesting and I wanted to understand them. I love linq lambda expressions and this seemed similar

Comment: @Yablargo Totally resonable. I LOVE list comps and dict comps.